# Get count and details of each count details

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table called 'A' and another table called 'B'.
Here in table A i keep all the master details and where B it keeps the status of field A like approved, rejected. 
My need is i need a single query with output as

```
{
   submitted_count: 5,
   {[details of first app], [details of 2 app], [], [],[]},
   rejected_count : 2,
   {[details of first app],[details of second app]}
}
```

How would i achieve this ?

Comment: The table 'B' has a foreign key to table 'A', right ?!
The information is in a JSON column type or is in a 'traditional way'?

Comment: yes they do have the relations. they are in traditional way not in jsonb

Comment: Your doubt is how to do the query that return the expected result or how to convert the result of the query into the JSON object?

Comment: how to do that query is my doubt

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert the result of the query to JSON you need to use the *[json_agg](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/create-quick-json-data-dumps-from-postgresql)* function.

```
select json_agg(t)
from (
  Select
        count(1) as total,
        string_agg(tb.detail,',') as details        
       FROM A tb
        inner join B tbb
            on tb.id = tbB.id_A
        where  tbb.status = true
       union 
       Select
        count(1) as total,
        string_agg(tb.detail,',') as details        
       FROM A tb
           inner join B tbb
               on tb.id = tbB.id_A
       where  tbb.status = false
) t;
```

The output is a little bit different:

```
[{"total":2,"details":"Bob,Logan"},{"total":3,"details":"Scott,Jean,Gambit"}]
```

There is an example [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6WrLVvH2P3odLAM4BFKavx/2) how to use it

Comment: Can you please help to resolve the syntax error ?<l> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76UK3AvAtR4HZUgVfWH6mz/0 <l>

Comment: Thank you Diogo ! i did some more alteration but got stuck with a syntax error, can you please help ? link  is https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76UK3AvAtR4HZUgVfWH6mz/0

Comment: done some more works and finally getting error "Query Error: error: could not identify an equality operator for type json"  link attached https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5kzT1y4SSQ9kq6KvXr4vXa/0

Comment: Thanks i resolved it by myself. instead of union i used union all, as json tried to compare the result value one among the other i used union all where it will ignore even if duplicate. forked the result for your kind verification and reference. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjo4EaWo9ToJAQ8dYuLReL/0

Comment: Hi am getting duplicate count name even after setting the alias in both the union fields. to see the exact problem i request to go to the page https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJM73t7Rq4aQJ4S7dAW5q7/0  here if you see the submmited count as  2 and again submmited count as 3 where expected the header name as pending count

Comment: Hi @JithinKumarS, it won't work because of union combine de result-set, so you would need create a new empty column in the query, take a look into [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wJM73t7Rq4aQJ4S7dAW5q7/1)